# Check if week, quarter, day and month fall between dates

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have multiple options which I want to check:

- If a **week** of a given **year** is between **startDate** and
  **endDate**.
- If a **quarter** of a given **year** is between **startDate** and
  **endDate**.
- If a **month** of a given **year** is between **startDate** and
  **endDate**.
- If a **day** is between **startDate** and
  **endDate**.

My existing code, which works fine for when the **startDate** **year** equals the **endDate** **year**, however if the **startDate** or **endDate** is in a different **year** it does not work obviously:

```
void ForWeek(int year, int week) 
{
    // throw if week < 1 or week > 53

    if (startYear == year && endYear == year
        && (ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(x.StartDate) == week && ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(x.EndDate) == week))
    {
        
    }
}
```

I also need a function which does the same for **day**, **month** and **quarter**.

My existing quarter method:

```
void ForQuarter(int year, int quarter) 
{
    // throw if quarter < 0 or quarter > 4

    if (startYear == year && endYear == year 
        && (((x.StartDate.Month + 2) / 3) == quarter && ((x.EndDate.Month + 2) / 3 == quarter)))
    {
        
    }
}
```

My existing day method:

```
void ForDay(DateTime day)
{
    if (x.StartDate.Date == day.Date && x.EndDate.Date == day.Date)
    {

    }
}
```

I do not have a month function yet:

```
void ForMonth(int year, int month)
{
    // throw if month < 1 or month > 12
    
    if (...) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing for equality (`==`), you should check if the year is greater than the start year, or is equal to the start year and the week is greater than or equal to the start week and the inverse for the end. So basically: `if ((year > startYear || (year == startYear && week >= startWeek)) && (year < endYear || (year == endYear && week <= endWeek)))` .
`startWeek` and `endWeek` are just shortened versions of your week calculations for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works and I was able to use it to modify it for the other cases.

Comment: I don't quite get your problem, if you have a `startDate` and an `endDate` why can't you just do `if (startDate <= weekStart && endDate >= weekEnd)`? For quarters, months and days it's especially easy, because those have fixed start and enddays too. For weeks it might be a bit more effort to find the startdate of the week

Comment: @derpirscher It doesn't work since startDate and endDate are both DateTimes, where weekStart or weekEnd would be int? I don't know exactly what you mean by weekStart and weekEnd. Nevertheless, you need to check the year or your method would most likely be true for every year and I want to check for a week in a year.

Comment: Well, then find the weekstart as DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Due to @JeanotZubler's answer, I was able to modify their code in order to fit the other scenarios.

---

In case anyone would like to achieve the things I wanted, here are my methods:

**Year:**

```
(year > startDate.Year || year == startDate.Year) && (year < endDate.Year || year == endDate.Year)
```

**Quarter:**

```
(year > startDate.Year || (year == startDate.Year && ((startDate.Month + 2) / 3) == quarter)) && (year < endDate.Year || (year == endDate.Year && ((endDate.Month + 2) / 3) == quarter))
```

**Month:**

```
(year > startDate.Year || (year == startDate.Year && startDate.Month == month)) && (year < endDate.Year || (year == endDate.Year && endDate.Month == month))
```

**Week:**

```
(year > startDate.Year || (year == startDate.Year && week >= ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(startDate))) && (year < endDate.Year || (year == endDate.Year && week <= ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(endDate)))
```

**Day:**

```
day >= startDate && day <= endDate
```

**Date range:**

```
startDate >= start && endDate <= end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it as follows:

The methods takes 5 parameters

- `type` period type to look at (0 = day, 1 = week, 2 = month, 3= quarter)
- `number` the number of the period within the year
- `year` the year to look at
- `startDate`
- `endDate`

How does it work:

- First it determines the `pstart` (ie the beginning) of the period in question. This is quite easy for day, month and quarter. For the beginning of a week, you need a bit more code (or a respective library which calculates that for you)
- Then add a whole period to that `pstart` (ie 1 day, 7 days, 1 month, 3 months). This gives you the beginning of the *next* period (ie the first instant in time that is *not* contained in the period in question)

With these two dates, you can now easily check

```
if (startDate <= pstart && endDate >= pend)
```

ie, if you whole period from `[pstart, pend)` is contained between `startDate` and `endDate`. This makes an explicit check for the year obsolete.

Calculating `pend` as the beginning of the next period instead of the end of the current period makes this comparison easier, because you don't have to deal with the time of the day. For instance if you are checking the 3rd month of 2023 and your `endDate = 2023-03-31T14:00:00`. Should that count as contained or not. Technically it's not, because march ends at `2023-03-31-23:59:59.999999` So to handle this situation correctly, you would need to set the enddate to `2023-03-31T23:59:59.999999` but depending on the timeresolution of your system, this still leaves an (admittedly tiny) space for errors, which is eliminated by setting `pend` to `2023-04-01T00:00:00`. Furthermore, this also makes finding the end of a month or and of a quarter easier, because those periods don't have a fixed number of days. So getting the  31st of March from the 1st of march is different from getting the 30th of April from the 1st of April. But adding a number of months will always bring you to the 1st of the desired month ...

```
public static bool isInRange(int type, int number, int year, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    DateTime pstart, pend;
    switch (type) {
        case 0:  //day
            if (number < 1 || number > (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365)) throw new ArgumentException("invalid day");
            //add number -1 days to Jan 1st
            pstart = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(number - 1); // the given day
            pend = pstart.AddDays(1); //the next day
            break;
        case 1:  //week
            if (number < 1 || number > 53) throw new ArgumentException("invalid week");
            //following ISO Week definition here, IE start of week is Monday, and first week of the year is the one
            //with the first thursday in the year
            pstart = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            switch(pstart.DayOfWeek) {
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(1);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(-1);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(-2);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(-3);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(3);
                    break;
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                    pstart = pstart.AddDays(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            //add number - 1 weeks to start of week 1
            pstart = pstart.AddDays(7 * (number -1));
            pend = pstart.AddDays(7);
            break;
        case 2: //month
            if (number < 1 || number > 12) throw new ArgumentException("invalid month");
            pstart = new DateTime(year, number, 1);  //first day of given month
            pend = pstart.AddMonths(1);  //first day of next month
            break;
        case 3: //quarter
            if (number < 1 || number > 4) throw new ArgumentException("invalid quarter");
            pstart = new DateTime(year, 1 + (number -1) * 3, 1); //first day of the quarter
            pend = pstart.AddMonths(3); //first day of next quarter
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid type");
    }
    
    return startDate >= pstart && endDate < pend;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however your numbers are quite different than mine, except for the day. If I check the quarter with the following date 2021-1-1 to 2021-3-31 for the first quarter, it's false, however if check for 2021-1-1 to 2021-4-1 then it's true, where it should be false.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I accidentally switched the comparators at the final comparison ...